# What does `--frontend` do in `do-release-upgrade` and where can I find the list of possible values?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

While checking the [manual for `do-release-upgrade`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html#options), I found out that it has a `--frontend` argument that can be passed to the command along with a value. However, the manpage doesn't explain what the argument exactly does, or what are the available values for it.

```
       -f FRONTEND, --frontend=FRONTEND
              Run the specified frontend
```

My assumption is that it to allow us to go through a specific application like the Software Updater or the command-line. Can I find a better description and a list of possible values for that argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateManagerFaq

> There are also different user interfaces for the release upgrader. Those can be changed via "--frontend" and the following are available "DistUpgradeViewText", "DistUpgradeViewGtk", "DistUpgradeViewKDE".

Unfortunately, the wiki links for these options show

> This page does not exist yet.

Comment: This is confirmed by a reading of the source code: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader/tree/do-release-upgrade. Text is the shell do-release-upgrade command, GTK is the Gnome-based Software Updater, KDE is the K-based similar. All three use this common script under the hood.

Comment: Wow!  I expected a whole lot more from Canonical.  What's the point of an incomplete `man` page?  Not even a link at the bottom to at least point the user to the source code!  Even worse, there's no mention of `DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive`

Comment: Wondered how often this `--frontend` option is used ... and why use `gui` through commands - or did I understand wrong the idea?

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit this answer, since the Wiki page they're quoting is wrong. The GTK option is now `DistUpgradeViewGtk3`, per the source code link posted by @user535733 and my personal verification that it only spawns the GUI with `3` on the end.

Comment: Any Ubuntu Member can edit the wiki page. Others can with a simple request for permission. The wiki pages are intended to be maintained by the community (you). Edits of the wiki and of this answer should specify which releases of Ubuntu are/are-not affected by the change. Many (most!) folks use older releases.